# YouTube app not preloading

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, downloading, youtube

I have a Nexus 7 running 4.4.2. I have one video in my "Watch Later" list in the YouTube app, which successfully preloaded a few weeks ago. I have the preload setting activated.

I have added a second video to the list, but it will not start preloading. The device is connected to a wifi network with excellent signal strength and is connected to a computer via the USB cable to charge. The battery icon indicates that it is charging.

I removed the video from the list, restarted the YouTube app and added it again, but it will not start preloading. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Preloading no longer available on version 5.6 and above.

[source](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/4629400)

Comment: 5.6 only started rolling out on 16th April so I don't think this is the issue the OP has. They also mention that they have the setting activated which implies they still have the option to preload.